# How to hide a plugin metabox for non admins when a user adds a new post

Tags: functions, metabox

I've been able to disable all the meta boxes for non admin in their backend but I'm having problems with **Facebook AWD All in one** which creates a widget seen by all the users when they create new posts.
How can I disable it? Is there some sort of command that is good for any widget created by plugins that I can add in my functions.php if I know the shortcode of the plugin?
I need your help!
Thanks...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-awd/

I use the following code to remove meta boxes

```
######################################################################
# remove evreything from add a new post
######################################################################
if (is_admin()) :
function remove_post_meta_boxes() {
 if(!current_user_can('administrator')) {
  remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'normal');
//remove_meta_box('categorydiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('postimagediv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('authordiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('revisionsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('authordiv', 'post', 'normal');
  remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
 }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_post_meta_boxes' );
endif;
```

This is the code of the metabox
    
    
    
Facebook AWD Manager

```
    <div class="AWD_facebook_wrap">

        <h2>Like Button</h2>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <div class="AWD_facebook_likebutton"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.dogsheaven.net/?p=703" data-send="0" data-layout="standard" data-width="250" data-show-faces="0" data-action="like" data-colorscheme="light" data-font="arial" data-ref=""></div></div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">

    <div class="span3">
        <label for="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_redefine">Redefine globals settings ?</label>
        <select id="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_redefine" name="awd_fcbk_option_like_button[redefine]" class="span3" >
        <option value="0" selected="selected" >No</option><option value="1"  >Yes</option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <label for="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_enabled">Activate ?</label>
        <select id="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_enabled" name="awd_fcbk_option_like_button[enabled]" class="span3" >
        <option value="0"  >No</option><option value="1" selected="selected" >Yes</option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <label for="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_place">Where ?</label>
        <select id="awd_fcbk_option_like_button_place" name="awd_fcbk_option_like_button[place]" class="span3" >
        <option value="top" selected="selected" >Top</option><option value="bottom"  >Bottom</option><option value="both"  >Both</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Please, add a link to the plugin. Does the shortcode has relation with the meta box?

Comment: Forgot it. Just added...

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to turn off widgets?

Comment: Just added the code I use to turn off some of the metaboxes

Comment: Removed my answer as I didn't read your question properly. Man, that is one eyesore of a plugin.

Comment: Vancoder, why you say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this line to your code example for the `admin_menu` filter:

```
remove_meta_box('awd_fcbk_awd_mini_form_metabox', 'post', 'side');
```

where `awd_fcbk` is the plugin slug.

**Edit:**

This is the metabox that I'm targeting from the plugin source code:

```
//Like button manager on post page type
            add_meta_box($this->plugin_slug . "_awd_mini_form_metabox", __('Facebook AWD Manager', $this->ptd) . ' <img style="vertical-align:middle;" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="' . $this->plugin_url_images . 'facebook-mini.png" alt="facebook logo"/>', array(&$this, 'post_manager_content'), $type, 'side', 'core');
```

Comment: This one gives me the following error
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function remove_meta_box() in /home/dogsheav/public_html/wp-content/themes/Simpatia/functions.php on line 639

Comment: Did you place it into the above `admin_menu` filter code example?

Comment: That was the problem...

Comment: ok great, good luck with your project ;-)

Comment: Just a question... why you set it as high instead of normal?
Btw thanks for showing me how to exclude meta boxes in the future...

Comment: I updated the answer, after I took a look at the plugin source code, so you can see how the metabox is constructed. I removed the 'high' part, since it was a mistake, I meant to have written 'side' ;-)